locate and extract value of an element with multiple div and parent class using Python + Playwright
I am trying to create an automated job application program. This program will apply jobs that match the search criteria. One of the search criteria is to check if the job title has text "Programmer" in it. The search result is usually 20 pages with for 20 titles on each page. Need to check the title name before clicking and going through the apply flow. The jobs board is Dice.com. Using Python + playwright so as to perform some assertions in the flow.
The first step which is to obtain job title text. Unable to locate and extract value of title as it is nested in multiple parent div/class.
Example: job title from Dice jobs board: Test Manager - CCAR/CECL

Trying to get the list of job titles on each page to be used as input for another function.
Full Xpath: /html/body/dhi-js-dice-client/div/dhi-search-page-container/dhi-search-page/div/div[2]/dhi-search-page-results/div/div[3]/js-search-display/div/div[3]/dhi-search-cards-widget/div/dhi-search-card[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h5/a
Trying to replicate what has been done in this article but with Dice.com as jobs board.
Tried the below:
import asyncio
from os import name
import re
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
    browser = await p.chromium.launch()
    page = await browser.new_page()
    await page.goto("https://www.dice.com/dashboard/login")
    await page.get_by_placeholder("Please enter your email").fill("Email")
    await page.get_by_role("button", name=re.compile("Continue", re.IGNORECASE)).click()
    await page.get_by_placeholder("Enter Password").fill("Password")
    await page.get_by_role("button", name=re.compile("Sign In", re.IGNORECASE)).click()
    await page.get_by_role("button", name=re.compile("Search Jobs", re.IGNORECASE)).click()
    await page.get_by_role("button", name=re.compile("Posted Date", re.IGNORECASE)).click()
    await page.get_by_role("button", name=re.compile("Posted Date", re.IGNORECASE)).click()
    await page.get_by_role("radio", name=re.compile("Today", re.IGNORECASE)).click()
    await page.get_by_label("Contract").click()
    job_card = await page.locator("dhi-search-card").all()
    for card in job_card:
       job_element = card.locator("a")
       job_title = job_element.inner_html()
       print("Job Title:", job_title)

 asyncio.run(main())

The code in the article is working for that jobs board which is much simple structure than Dice website.
